# Magento 1.X put label after System > Configuration element

Tags: magento

I'm making a System > Configuration extension where as a developer you can specify a file where all requests will be logged. It's just a textfield where you can fill in any name you want.

What I would like to add is '.log' just after the textfield so users don't write that down instead of having to display (don't add .log).

My question is simple: 
Is this possible? And if so, how?

Here's the code I use inside my system.xml

```
  <requestfile translate="label">
        <label>Resuest log filename (don't add .log)</label>
        <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
        <sort_order>1</sort_order>
        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
  </requestfile>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Soo...
Magento can't do it apparently.
What I could do, and did by accident, is add

```html
<validate>validate-code</validate>
```

to the system.xml

This ensures that the user can only input a-z, 0-9 or _ 
So no . so no .log

As easy as that.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to achieve something like following
[image]

Try following

```
<requestfile translate="label">
    <label>Resuest log filename (don't add .log)</label>
     <comment><![CDATA[Your comment text comes here]]></comment>
    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
    <sort_order>1</sort_order>
    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
</requestfile>
```

Notice the `<comment></comment>` tag in  the code given above.You should write your message or comment there.

Comment: This put's the text underneath but I just want to display the box with '.log' behind it. As in |_______|.log